# OpenProcess gives "Sub or Function not defined" error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VBA in Excel and am trying to use the popular ShellAndWait subroutine.  Within this sub is a call to OpenProcess, but that is giving me a compile error "Sub or Function not defined."  I've tried to research why this would come up and can't find anything.  Is there a specific Reference I need to set up in VBA to use this?  I don't have admin rights on this machine--could that be a problem?  Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you declared OpenProcess?

```
Declare Function OpenProcess Lib “kernel32” (ByVal dwDesiredAcess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
```

Comment: Thanks, DReJ--I had actually just found that I needed the following declarations:  Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwDesiredAccessas As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcId As Long) As Long

Private Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000
Private Const INFINITE = &HFFFFFFFF;  but even after adding those, I still get the error.

Comment: P.S.  Why can't a comment be edited in the same way as an answer on this forum (no carriage returns or formatting)?  Makes me want to use an answer to reply, though that doesn't seem like the right approach either (and was discouraged by SO).

Comment: Sorry, DReJ--just tried it again, and it worked.  It was those missing declarations.  I really appreciate your help!